# How to compare user input to a randomly generated number?

Tags: python

So I made a "Guess the Number" program with Python and tested it. Apparently, choosing the correct number still comes up as the incorrect `else` statement. How can I fix this?

As you can see the `3` I entered apparently isn't the same as the `3` my program came up:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Post all code here directly as text instead of linking to images.

Comment: `print(type(usernum), type(EasyRN))`

Comment: What do you mean by a "computer 3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the return value of your call to `input` (the string in your variable `usernum`) with the return value of `random.randint` which is an integer in your variable `EasyRN`.

You'll need to convert either the integer into an string:

```py
usernum = int(usernum)
```

Or the string into an integer:

```py
EasyRN = str(EasyRN)
```

Afterwards, you can use `==` to compare them.

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

The result of `input()` is *text* (in Python, a `str`, short for the word "string" which is used in programming), while the output of `random.randint()` is a *number* (an `int`, short for "integer").

```py
>>> type("3")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(3)
<class 'int'>
```

If you compare a `str` and an `int` they will never be equivalent, as it's an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Look at the `int()` function which converts a string to an integer.

```py
>>> int("3")
3
>>> type(int("3"))
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind next time :)